# TFS - GitVersion - A supported task execution handler was not found

Tags: tfs, gitversion

I have on-prem TFS 2015, and want to run gitversion, so added step as below:

[image]

GitVersion.yml:

```
mode: Mainline
branches:
  feature:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: rc
    increment: Minor
    source-branches:
      - master
  fix:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: rc
    increment: Patch
    regex: ^fix[/-]
  bug:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: rc
    increment: Patch
    regex: '(bug(fix(es)?)?|support)[/-]'
    source-branches:
      - master
  upgrade:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: rc
    increment: Major
    regex: '(upgrade|major)[/-]'
    source-branches:
      - master
```

Build agent is on windows server, installed GitVersion

```
dotnet tool install --global GitVersion.Tool --version 5.*
```

But pipeline fails

```
2022-11-10T11:43:24.9727477Z ##[section]Starting: gitversion/execute
2022-11-10T11:43:24.9934703Z ==============================================================================
2022-11-10T11:43:24.9934703Z Task         : Execute GitVersion Task
2022-11-10T11:43:24.9934703Z Description  : Easy Semantic Versioning (http://semver.org) for projects using Git
2022-11-10T11:43:24.9934703Z Version      : 0.9.15
2022-11-10T11:43:24.9934703Z Author       : GitTools Contributors
2022-11-10T11:43:24.9934703Z Help         : See the [documentation](https://gitversion.net/docs/) for help
2022-11-10T11:43:24.9934703Z ==============================================================================
2022-11-10T11:43:25.4018670Z ##[error]A supported task execution handler was not found. This error usually means the task does not carry an implementation that is compatible with your current operating system. Contact the task author for more details.
2022-11-10T11:43:25.4018670Z ##[section]Finishing: gitversion/execute
```

Comment: What update level of TFS 2015 are you using? The documentation specifies it will not work unless you're using TFS 2015 Update 2. That said, there's no need to use an extension. You can run `gitversion` from the command line. All the task is doing is wrapping the CLI.

Comment: at the end, i used command line and it worked

Comment: Hi, if you have a solution or workaround, could you please [post answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)? This will help other who meet the similar issue.

Comment: sorry, forgot to do it earlier, done, please note i can accept my answer after 18 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On build machine downloaded [gitversion](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/releases) to C:\GitVersion folder then on CI/CD pipeline added task execute command

```
C:\GitVersion\GitVersion.exe /output buildserver /nofectch
```